# Copy / Paste Data in Ajax Live Search

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, search, live

I'm working with **Ehsan Abbasi's Ajax Live Search (ALS)**

- https://github.com/iranianpep/ajax-live-search
- http://ajaxlivesearch.com/

which invokes MySQL, PHP & jQuery to search and display search suggestion results as you type (similarly to popular search engines).

**I'm struggling with the following:**

1. When the user copies data and pastes it into the form, thereby rendering the live search pointless, what is the syntax to pass that data into the submitted form?
2. What does "onResultEnter" refer to? The user hits the enter button?
3. What does "onAjaxComplete" refer to? The user clicks a submit button?

**Here's my relevant work to put these issues into context.**

**First, we initialize some variables and connect to our database via PHP:**

```
# Live search initialization.
# --
file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/als/core/Handler.php') ? require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/als/core/Handler.php' : die('Handler.php not found');
file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/als/core/Config.php')  ? require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/als/core/Config.php'  : die('Config.php not found');

use AjaxLiveSearch\core\Config;
use AjaxLiveSearch\core\Handler;

if (session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}

$handler = new Handler();
$handler->getJavascriptAntiBot();

# Connect to database.
# --
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/connect.php");
global $dbc;

# Initialize required CSS and JavaScript files to be included.
# --
$additional_css = "<link href=\"/als/css/ajaxlivesearch.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />";
$additional_js = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/als/js/ajaxlivesearch.js\"></script>";
```

**We next include two distinct forms to execute unrelated searches:**

```
<!-- Model number search form -->

<form role="form" id="productsSearch" action="search-models.php" method="get" class="search-form">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="model_number" id="models" class="form-control modelSearch" placeholder="Enter your model number">
        <input type="hidden" name="model_number" id="model_number">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return model_validator();">Go</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>

<!-- Part number search form -->

<form onsubmit="return part_validator();" action="search-parts.php" role="form" method="get">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="part_number" id="parts" class="form-control partSearch" placeholder="Enter your part number">
        <input type="hidden" name="part_number" id="part_number">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Note here that the model search form involves an onclick event to validate model numbers. Similarly, the part number search form invokes an onsubmit event to validate part numbers. Both of these events were in our custom code before ALS entered the picture.

In addition, we have included a hidden field in each form to contain the value selected by the user in the ALS to be passed into the form when submitted to the action scripts.

**These hidden field values are set in ALS functions associated with each of these input forms:**

```
<!-- Model search: ALS functions -->

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".modelSearch").ajaxlivesearch({

            onResultClick: function(e, data) {

                // Get the index 0 (first column) value.
                var selectedOne = jQuery(data.selected).find('td').eq('0').text();

                // Set the input value.
                jQuery('#models').val(selectedOne);

                // Hide the result.
                jQuery("#models").trigger('ajaxlivesearch:hide_result');

                // Set the hidden field value.
                $('input[name=model_number]').val(selectedOne);

            },

            onResultEnter: function(e, data) {

                // What does this refer to? The user hits the enter button?

            },

            onAjaxComplete: function(e, data) {

                // What does this refer to? The user clicks a submit button?

            }
        });
    })
</script>

<!-- Part search: ALS functions -->

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".partSearch").ajaxlivesearch({

            onResultClick: function(e, data) {

                // Get the index 0 (first column) value.
                var selectedOne = jQuery(data.selected).find('td').eq('0').text();

                // Set the input value.
                jQuery('#parts').val(selectedOne);

                // Hide the result.
                jQuery("#parts").trigger('ajaxlivesearch:hide_result');

                // Set the hidden field value.
                $('input[name=part_number]').val(selectedOne);

            },

            onResultEnter: function(e, data) {

                // What does this refer to? The user hits the enter button?

            },

            onAjaxComplete: function(e, data) {

                // What does this refer to? The user clicks a submit button?

            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

I'd very much appreciate any help troubleshooting the syntax to get data that's copied by users from unknown sources & pasted into either of these forms and passed into the form action search scripts.  Any light that could be shed on the onResultEnter and onAjaxComplete functions would likewise be welcomed.

If there's any additional information I can pass along to assist troubleshooting, do please let me know!

Best,
Allison

Comment: Maybe this link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408747/i-can-use-some-advise-on-ajaxlivesearch-com-function-in-jquery also give a read to http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/ I hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately, this wasn't the information I needed to resolve the copy/paste issue cited. Thanks for the response, though.